# Navbar cuts into Carousel images

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Looks like I've got a problem and I'm not sure the next step.  I think I've beaten my head against the css wall with position, margin, padding, and the like.

I just need to move my carousel below my navbar and yet keep them both fixed...any ideas?

Code:

```css
.carousel-inner .carousel-item {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

.hero1 {
  background: url(hero.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
}
.hero2 {
  background: url(hero2.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
}
.hero3 {
  background: url(hero3.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
}

.navbar {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica;
  font-weight: 200;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px #2a2a2a;
}

.navbar-inverse a.navbar-brand {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica;
  font-weight: 100;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
    <div id="carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>
      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="carousel-item hero1 active">
          <img class="d-block img-fluid">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item hero2">
          <img class="d-block img-fluid">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item hero3">
          <img class="d-block img-fluid">
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
```

https://github.com/peterbehere/christ_the_king_fellowship_app.git

Comment: A working example of what you currently have in https://jsfiddle.net/ or https://codepen.io/ would help others with helping you

Comment: Perhaps you should include the navbar in your code.

Comment: Thanks for that.  I'll update.

Comment: https://codepen.io/peterbehere/pen/jBjeKp

Comment: Full code for application.html.erb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE:  I figured it out!  First, I completely removed the CSS that pointed to my images.  Then, I replaced the html img class with rails image_tag helpers.  This now works!

```
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <%= image_tag "hero.jpg", :id =>"hero1",  :class =>"d-block img-fluid" %>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <%= image_tag "hero2.jpg", :id =>"hero2",  :class =>"d-block img-fluid" %>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <%= image_tag "hero3.jpg", :id =>"hero3",  :class =>"d-block img-fluid" %>
    </div>
```